# Combine onload, onresize and onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function below runs on document load and document resize:

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
// code
}).resize();
```

How can I also trigger the function when the user clicks on `<div id="my_div"></div>` ?

Comment: Always remember: anonymous functions are only a feature of the language. There's nothing that forces you to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your function to some named function and call it on event:

```
function myFunction () {
    alert('Working');
}

$(window).on("resize", function () {
    myFunction();
}).resize();

$('#my_div').click(function () {
    myFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly create the callback function, like..

```
function callbackFn() {
  var $caller = $(this);
  // do something...
}

$(window).on('resize', callbackFn);
$('#my_div').on('click', callbackFn);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achive that is by triggering the resize event inside the click event handler:

```
$('#my_div').on('click', function() {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```